# Error when Displaying Data in a Chart with ASP.NET Web Pages (Razor)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

```
@{
    var myChart = new Chart(width: 600, height: 400)
    .AddTitle("Employees")
    .AddSeries(chartType: "column",
    xValue: new[] { "Peter", "Andrew", "Julie", "Mary", "Dave" },
    yValues: new[] { "2", "6", "4", "5", "3" })
    .Write();
 }
```

I am using the sample code from msdn, but got this Error: ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
 Parameter name: httpContext
Can anyone help me out?

Comment: It works fine for me. Can you post the code for all of the view, as well as the action in your controller that calls the view.